# From selected canvas image want to get height, width of the selected image size

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

```
{left: 51, right: 508, top: 676, bottom: 477}
```

Got above bounds from a cropped image,
I just want height and width form this calculation can this is possible ?
[You can see in this image](http://prntscr.com/jmgsmj)

Or there are any properties for getting that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.canvasWidth = $scope.bounds.right - $scope.bounds.left;
$scope.canvasHeight = $scope.bounds.top - $scope.bounds.bottom;
```

- you can get width and height from above calculation
- I hope it will be help some other guys